# What is the size of udp packets if I send 0 payload data in c#?

Tags: c#, header, udp, packet, udpclient

I have figured out the maximum data before fragmentation between 2 endpoints using udp is 1472(other endpoints may vary). This states that mtu is 1500bytes and header overhead per packet is 28bytes. Is it safe to assume that if I send 0 bytes data (payload), the actual data being transferred is 28bytes? I am doing some benchmark, so it is crucial for me to know, what happens in the channel.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- The MTU is the maximum size of an IP packet that can be transmitted without fragmentation.

  IPv4 mandates a path MTU of at least 576 bytes, IPv6 of at least 1280 bytes.

  Ethernet has an MTU of 1500 bytes.
- An IP packet is composed of two parts: the packet header and the payload.

  The size of an IPv4 header is *at least* 20 bytes, the size of an IPv6 header *at least* 40 bytes.

  The payload of an IP packet is typically a TCP segment or a UDP datagram.
- A UDP datagram consists of a UDP header and the transported data.

  The size of a UDP header is 8 bytes.

This means an IP packet with an empty UDP datagram as payload takes **at least** 28 (IPv4) or 48 (IPv6) bytes, but may take more bytes.

Also note that in the case of Ethernet, the IP packet will additionally be wrapped in a MAC packet (14 byte header + 4 byte CRC) which will be embedded in an Ethernet frame (8 byte preamble sequence). This adds 26 bytes of data to the IP packet, but doesn't count against the MTU.

So you cannot assume that a UDP datagram will cause a specific number of bytes to be transmitted.

Comment: im a bit confuse. are you saying that even with 1500bytes for mtu, the actual packet data can be more than 1500bytes(+26)? how can perform accurate measurement if i dont know how much data is actually sent? is there anyway for me to know how much data is actaully transferred?

Comment: so what is the answer?

Comment: @thang 48 bytes over IPv6 or 28 bytes over IPv4.

Answer (score 10):

Typical IP headers are 20 bytes, if no options have been selected. UDP headers are 8 bytes. Over Ethernet, frame size is 14 bytes (header) + 4 bytes (trailer). Depending on how you capture these packets, you may or may not have to account for frame size.

Without Ethernet (IP + UDP) = 20 + 8 = 28 bytes
With Ethernet = 18 + 28 = 46 bytes

The UdpClient class in C# will return the packet from layer 5 onwards, so you won't have to account for the above.

**Update:**
The 1500 bytes MTU is enforced at the IP layer. That means that the packet size below the IP layer is insignificant when fragmenting.

That translates to:
Ethernet frame bytes (fixed) = 18
IP header (min) = 20
UDP header (fixed) = 8
Max. allowed payload for no fragmentation = 1472
Total number of bytes that go on the wire = (Sum above) 1518 bytes
(You can count the number of bytes leaving with a tool like Wireshark)

If (IP header + UDP header + Payload > 1500) then the packet is fragmented.

Comment: so you mean without ehternet the header would be 28bytes which results to 1472 maximum payload and with ethernet the header is 46 bytes which results to 1454 maximum payload. the method i use to get the maximum payload is to set dontfragment flag of udpclient to true and sending data stating with 1500 payload size. c# will fire an exception if the data will be fragmented and i reduce the payload size until no exception is fired. is this ok?

Comment: The max. you can send out is 1472, irrespective of what is done below the IP layer. Updated answer.

Comment: is there a way to determine if the user between endpoints is using ethernet in c# or whether Ethernet frame bytes (fixed) is used? is it safe to assume that all people connected to the internet are using ethernet(people, not organization that uses fibre channel etc)? looking at wiki definition of ethernet, it is described as lan devices.

Comment: is it safe to say that if i send packets with 1472 bytes of payload, the total data flow through the ethernet channel is 1518? thanks.

Comment: is it safe to say that if i send packets with 0 bytes of payload, the total data flow through the ethernet is 46 bytes?

Comment: Yes, both should be right. Though I'd suggest verifying with Wireshark.

Comment: Some sources like wikipedia says that the use of the fields "Checksum" and "Source port" is optional in IPv4 UDP header. So does that mean, that if I want to turn off these 2 fields I would save 4 bytes from the UDP header size ?

Answer (score 8):

> Is it safe to assume that if i send 0 bytes data(payload), the actual data being transferred is 28bytes

### No

(and yes... because it usually makes no real difference, insofar it is "safe")

While it is true that a no-payload-no-option UDP/IPv4 datagram is exactly 28 bytes (or "octets" in network jargon), this is by no means a safe assumption.
It is, however, for the most part inconsequential. Switches and routers usually forward a small packet exactly as fast as a larger one (or, with neglegible difference). The only occasion at which you may see a difference is on your bandwidth bill (you pay for all bits on the wire, not just for the ones that you use!).

IPv4 may have up to 40 octets of "options" attached to it, and IPv4 may be encapsulated in IPv6 (without you knowing, even). Both could drastically increase the datagram's size and thus data transferred in a rather obvious way.

Also, the datagram will be further encapsulated on the link layer, both adding preambles and header data, and having minimum frame lengths. The presence of additional headers is, again, pretty obvious, the fact that besides maximum sizes, payloads also have **minimum** sizes is a less well-known fact.

Ethernet and ATM are two widely used standards that can get in your way on your assumptions here (but other link layers are similar).

An ethernet frame has a minimum size of 64 bytes, and is zero-padded to this size. In presence of 802.1Q (VLAN) this means that the minimum payload for an ethernet frame is 42 octets, otherwise it is 46 octets.
Sending a zero-length UDP/IPv4 datagram over "ordinary" ethernet will therefore append 18 zero bytes to the payload. You never get to see them, but they are there and they will appear on your bill.

Similarly, ATM cells (same as "frame", they use a different word for some reason) are always 53 bytes, with 48 bytes of zero-padded payload. Thus, a zero-payload UDP diagram will cause 20 zero bytes being added whereas a zero-length UDP/IPv6 datagram would keep its original size (being exactly 48 bytes in size), assuming there is no other encapsulation such as PPPoE in between.

Lastly, do note that additional packets may be needed to be sent and received in order to being able to send your packet at all. For example, your ethernet card may have to do ARP (or NDP) to be able to send your datagram. Caching the results amortizes this as you are sending several datagrams, but if you send just *one* UPD datagram, you may be surprised that about three times as much "data" is sent and received compared to what you might naively expect.

Answer (score 1):

IP overhead is 20bytes and UDP is 8 btes, so yes, 28 bytes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

Don't forget about Ethernet overhead if you're doing internal testing

Comment: i did look at udp wiki, but to be honest, i dont really know what to look for. i dont understand much either. by the way, how can i measure this ethernet overhead?